# How to use rest webservice in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs4.1

I am new bee to extjs.I want to learn How to use rest webservice in extjs4.1.can anybody provide good tutorial ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good starting point: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide